# How to find the amplitude of a longitudinal wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

This diagram shows two centres of compression and one centre of rarefraction. I am able to find the wavelength, yet was unable to find the amplitude.

Based on the second picture, the amplitude should correspond to the distance between the centre of compression and the particle's position next to it.
Thus, my approach is to take the highlighted distance, which is around 0.4cm, but this is incorrect.Why is the amplitude 0.8cm?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: The second picture is just wrong when it comes to amplitude. Did your instructors provide it, or did you find it somewhere online?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I found it online. I wasn't sure about the amplitude back then, but I did notice that those lines are evenly spaced, which can't be the case..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of **amplitude**, whether for longitudinal or transverse waves, is the maximum distance from equilibrium that the media is displaced.

In the case of particles in a longitudinal waves, that means find which particle is the *furthest* away from it's resting point (in this case - the 3rd particle is 0.8 cm away from it's equilibrium point).